# remove() function of jQuery not working not removing span tag

Tags: jquery

This is my function which I am using to check if the same data exist in the database then an error would appear and some other data should be entered

The Jquery Function is not removing the previous tag instead it's keeping on adding the Text after every keypress.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_emp_no").keyup(function() {
    var emp_no = $(this).val();
    if (emp_no != "") {
      $.ajax({
          url: "{% url 'check_emp_no_exist' %}",
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            emp_no: emp_no
          }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
          if (response == "True") {
            $(".empno_error").remove();
            $("<span class='emp_no_error' style='color: red; padding: 5px; font-weight: bold;'> Employee No Not Available. </span>").insertAfter("#id_emp_no")
          } else {
            $(".empno_error").remove();
            $("<span class='emp_no' style='color: green; padding: 5px; font-weight: bold;'> Employee No Available. </span>").insertAfter("#id_emp_no")
          }
        })
      // }) // removed this
    } else {
      $(".empno_error").remove();
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_emp_no">Empno:</label>
  <input type="text" name="emp_no" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_emp_no">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make a snippet from your code but it gives error

Comment: Typo: You're removing `.empno_error`, you're adding `class="emp_no_error"`. These need to match.

Comment: I commented out the superfluous `})`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you found out the error thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler and safer

```js
$(function() {
  $("#id_emp_no").on("input", function() {
    $(".emp_no").hide();
    var emp_no = $(this).val();
    if (emp_no.trim() === "") return; // stop
    $.post("{% url 'check_emp_no_exist' %}", {emp_no: emp_no}, function(response) {
      $(".emp_no.error").toggle(response === "True");
      $(".emp_no.ok").toggle(response !== "True");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.emp_no {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

.emp_no.error {
  color: red;
}

emp_no.ok {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_emp_no">Empno:</label>
  <input type="text" name="emp_no" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_emp_no">
  <span class='emp_no error'>Employee No Not Available.</span>
  <span class='emp_no ok'>Employee No Available.</span>
</div>
```